# Django - create form doesn't work on live server

Tags: python, django, forms, nginx, uwsgi

I've got my form called **CreateTournamentForm** which is supposed to create the new tournament in system. When I work in localhost, everything is fine (no errors included). But when do the same on my server where I put this app, the same form doesn't work as on localhost. The page is just being refreshed and I'm getting the same form to fill (as I made it in my code if incorrect). The server stays on Ubuntu (nginx + uwsgi).

There are my samples of code:

**a) template.html:**

```
% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<form method="post" action="{{ request.path }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table" style="width: 23%">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label>
            <td>{{ form.name }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Start date:</label>
            <td>{{ form.start }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>End date:</label>
            <td>{{ form.end }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Martial arts:</label>
            <td>{{ form.type }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Regulations:</label>
            <td>{{ form.file }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Info:</label>
            <td>{{ form.description }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" value="Confirm"></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Back</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
{% endblock %}
{% block additional_js %}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**b) models.py":**

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
start = models.DateField()
end = models.DateField()
username = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

KYOKUSHIN = 'KYO'
SHOTOKAN = 'SHO'
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (KYOKUSHIN, 'kyokushin'),
    (SHOTOKAN, 'shotokan')
)
type = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
                        default=None,
                        null=True)
coaches = models.ManyToManyField(Coach, verbose_name="Lista trenerow", blank=True)
file = models.FileField(upload_to=file, verbose_name="Nazwa pliku")
description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

@property
def relative_path(self):
    return os.path.relpath(self.path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.name + " " + self.start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + " " + self.end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

**c) forms.py:**

```
class CreateTournamentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Tournament
    fields = ('name', 'start', 'end', 'type', 'file', 'description', )
    widgets = {
        'start': forms.DateInput(format=('%d/%m/%Y'), attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
        'end': forms.DateInput(format=('%d/%m/%Y'), attrs={'class': 'datepicker'})
    }
```

d) views.py:

```
@login_required
def createTournament(request):
template = loader.get_template('createtournament.html')

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreateTournamentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)

        tournament = Tournament(
            name=form.cleaned_data.get("name"),
            start=form.cleaned_data.get("start"),
            end=form.cleaned_data.get("end"),
            username=user,
            type=form.cleaned_data.get("type"),
            file=request.FILES.get("file"),
            description=form.cleaned_data.get("description")
        )
        tournament.save()

        Manager.objects.create(user_id=user, tournament=tournament)

        return redirect('/user/')
else:
    form = CreateTournamentForm()

return render_to_response('createtournament.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form, }))
```

Does anyone see the error ? Or maybe there is another problem ? Thanks for each response :)

Comment: Assuming that the formatting issues i see here are just due to copy paste, etc.. I see that you do `User.objects.get(user=request.user)` without a `login_required` decorator, or checking if the user is indeed logged in - are you sure you have logged in? Also (a minor note - ) it is better to use `render()` instead of `HttpResponse`

Comment: Hmm... You might be right with @login_required. I've just thought it's not really needed. I'm gonna check it also with "render". Thanks!

Comment: @karthikr: It doesn't work :/

Comment: @MaciejJanuszewski, at a quick glance, you're assigning your **Tournament** with `username=user` , and your **Manager** trying to create **(user_id=user)** which doesn't sound right here.

Comment: @Anzel, ok - good notice :) But my Manager model looks:
class Manager(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)

Comment: @MaciejJanuszewski, then your Tournament doesn't look right: assuming `username`=**string**, and you're passing a **User** object. Although without any stack trace, it will be very complicated to debug where your error is.

Comment: The other thing is The first line of the template is missing the opening `{` is that a copy paste erro ?

Comment: That's  a paste error :)